# unable to install HP Deskjet 2540 drivers

Tags: drivers, hp

I am new to this forum, so please let me know if I am using the wrong site for the question. I did have a deep dive into internet and this forum with no sucess.

I am running ubuntu 16.04 and trying to install my printer drivers but I reached a failing point I can't get rid of.

My printer is a HP Deskjet 2540 'all in one' printer. I went through the whole process described in the http://hplipopensource.com website installing the latest driver set HPLIP 3.16.7. It did install without a problem but when running the hp-setup program I can see my printer has been detected but the PPD file can't be found (I must say this exact printer model is supported by hplip):

error: No PPD found for model deskjet_2540 using old algorithm.
error: No appropriate print PPD file found for model deskjet_2540_series

Serching for the PPD in the /usr/share/ppd/ I've seen there isn't any single ppd for any Deskjet model including mine.

Lastly, I've seen this same quesiton has been asked in the past (some years ago) for other HP printers and older ubuntu distribution but I didn't see any clear solution.

Has anyone any idea about how to solve this?

Thanks in advance,

Nomar

Answer (score 0):

Install hplip and hplip-data if they are not already installed.  This should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered answered install hplip which pulls in hplip-data, then
on Debian 9.4 for example you seem to need a reboot of the computer and then go back into the printer settings and you can select the required driver HP Deskjet 2540 series. It also has the all in one scanner working out of the box.

You don't need to do the thing HP recommend, connect each pc via a usb cable!.